# QGIS: Execute an SQL Query after an update to PostGIS Layer

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have spatial data extended with a ranking all stored in postGIS and used as a Layer in a QGIS project.

I want to recalculate and update the ranking stored in a column once a edit/change to the layer properties occurs.

[image: QGIS Layer properties Actions]

QGIS has thing called "Actions". Can I used it for executing a prepared SQL-Statement after such a change has occured?

As only the QGIS project including the spatial data is under control of the team, I would prefer a solution which can be applied within QGIS.

Comment: The native solution would be to create a trigger on PostgreSQL side. That would also guarantee that ranking would be correct even if you update the table directly with SQL.

Comment: @Maus can you clarify if the spatial data are also saved in the PostGIS DB, or just the ranking? If both are in the same database, I'd also recommend solving this in the RDBMS, not QGIS.